# How to make 3 columns in Bootstrap where the last column is flexible and take the remaining space?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When removing `column2` how do I give the new extra space to `column3` ?

Do you set something else than `col-md-10` like some sort of `col-md-flex`? or do you change it dynamically/programmatically, when removing the `column2` ?

I have this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="column1" class="col-md-1" style="background-color: gray">
            <div>menu1</div>
            <div>menu1</div>
            <div>menu1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="column2" class="col-md-1" style="background-color: green">
            <div>menu2</div>
            <div>menu2</div>
            <div>menu2</div>
        </div>
        <div id="column3" class="col-md-10">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove column2, you can set the class of column3 to col-md-11

```
$('#column2').remove();
$('#column3').attr('class','col-md-11');
```

The bootstrap grid system (fluid or fixed width), uses a 12 column grid system to allow for a consistent layout across displays, so you have to set the width of the last div to take up the remaining columns (11 in this case) so that it will take up the correct proportion of the width (11/12 or 91.7% or 1067px on a 1170px container).